# YouTube Data V3 API videos.insert - wrong snippet.categoryID

Tags: youtube-api

I am trying to upload the video using V3 YouTube API.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert

I keep hitting HTTP 400 due to incorrect `snippet.categoryID` field. Is there any documentation on what available options on this field are?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the answer on YouTube itself. When you upload a video, use web developer tools in browser to inspect categories dropdown. It will contain category ids.

Comment: Looks like you can also get the category ids on this page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories/list